# Accessing a Sound-File via NSBundle - pathForResource

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, nsbundle

So I'm just trying to get into iOS Programming by going through some Online-Video-Courses. The problem is, that those are not up-to-date with Swift 3.

In the project I am at the moment it is required to import a Sound-File via the NSBundle-Framework using the following:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType:)
```

The problem is, that I won't get this running in Swift 3 and I'm not able to get the right pieces off the Apple Documentation. So my Code looks the following:

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation //don't know if this is right by 100 per cent

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("btn", ofType: "wav")
```

But it seems like It doesn't even know the Class NSBundle, because Auto-Completion isn't even offering me any functions of NSBundle. I can't seem to find the right pieces which changed in Swift 3 to get this thing working. Anybody here who's able to help me with this?

Comment: In swift 3 `NSBundle` is now `Bundle`.  `NSUserDefaults` is now `UserDefaults`.

Comment: [swift3-changes](https://www.appcoda.com/swift3-changes/)
`let file = Bundle.main().pathForResource(name, ofType: type)`
in swift3

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the ticket:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "btn", ofType: "wav")
```